# sort strings in csh

Tags: sorting, csh

```
set abc=( x1 y1 x2 y2 x21 y21 x22 y22 )
set new=`echo $abc | sort -kn`
echo $new
```

The above script gives me the same array.

I expect

```
x1 x2 x21 x22 y1 y2 y21 y22
```

Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` sorts by lines, and you're giving it just a single line of input.

This should work:

```
set abc = ( x1 y1 x2 y2 x21 y21 x22 y22 )
set new = `echo $abc | fmt -1 | sort -n`
echo $new
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked ! I can find very few references to csh coding. I wonder why !